# Prevent redirecting ASP.NET Core MVC Application after start

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

I've created an ASP.NET MVC Core 2 application with Azure authentication in visual studio 2017.

I register the application on Azure as well.

Now I click Ctrl+F5 to start the application from Visual Studio 2017.

I expected to see the main page, but it redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/blablablabla

But I want it to redirect only when user clicks *Sign in*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Asp.Net Core MVC 2.0` built-in template, it is used to `[Authorize]` to enable security request to access `[HomeController]`.

For `Asp.Net Core MVC 2.1` built-in template, it is used `[Authorize]` and `AuthorizeFilter` in `Startup`.

For your scenario, you are mostly fall in the second scenario.

Follow steps below:

- Remove the `[Authorize]` from `HomeController`.

  ```
  //[Authorize]
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         return View();
      }
  ```
- Remove `AuthorizeFilter` in `services.AddMvc`

  ```
          services.AddMvc(options =>
      {
          //var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
          //    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
          //    .Build();
          //options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
      })
      .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
  ```

Comment: Thank you. Removing AuthorizeFilter fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

To stop the redirect you need to find what’s causing it in first place. You can trigger a sign-in request usually in two ways -

1. Decorate your class/method with `[Authorize]` attribute which will force a sign-in request.
2. Issue an explicit challenge like shown below..

   ```
   return Challenge(
       new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
       OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   ```

I don't see enough details about your code in question.. to tell you where exactly to make a change in order to stop the redirect, but I can guess most probable cause and show you with a sample.

Here is a sample for ASP.NET core sample which has an explicit Sign-in Action with code available on GitHub.

[Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore)

Specifically, look at the AccountController to see how to force a sign in.

```
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
            var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home");
            return Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = redirectUrl },
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
```

Also, to make sure that I can see the home page without being forced to Sign-In, I just made a simple change in the sample code for HomeController.cs. I took out the `[Authorize]` attribute from the HomeController which was present in the original code in GitHub. (else you will be forced to sign-in as soon as you launch the application)

```
namespace WebApp_OpenIDConnect_DotNet.Controllers
{ 
    // notice there is no [Authorize] attribute now, to make landing page available without signin
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Now if someone clicks explicitly on SignIn link at the top, only then they are prompted for credentials. Just make sure you don't need any sensitive information on your home page since it's now available to everyone.

[image]

Comment: I removed [Authorize] attribute but it didn't help. Also, I don't use custom AccountController (there's no AccountController.cs in my project). For example, for sign in _<li><a asp-area="AzureAD" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SignOut">Sign out</a></li>._ Could be the reason?

Comment: @amplifier ok got it. Where you removed it from is important. Can you plz post your actual code and in case you’re following some sample, a URL to that as well.